# Sonar exception can not create ClassLoader

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I am running Sonar from Jenkins (Ant job, not maven) with `Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis` build step. I am getting the following error:

```
    15:46:46.369 INFO  .s.p.s.SquidExecutor - Java AST scan done: 33664 ms
    15:46:46.370 INFO  .s.p.s.SquidExecutor - Java bytecode scan...
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - ----- Classpath analyzed by Squid:
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/soap.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/axis_1.4.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xerces.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/json_simple.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jdom.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xml-apis.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-fileupload-1.0.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/httpclient-cache-4.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/datedFileAppender-1.0.2.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xmlParserAPIs.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/httpclient-4.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/axis_1.2.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jbossweb-2.1.7.GA.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/nekohtml.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/excalibur-i18n-1.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jawc.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jmxremote.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/httpcore-4.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xmlparserv2.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/junit.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-cli-1.0.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/axis-ant_1.2.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/rmissl.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/oc4j.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/servlet.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/trove.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-beanutils.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/axiom-api-1.2.7.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-net-1.4.0.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/j2ee.jar
    15:46:46.394 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/httpunit.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-collections-2.1.1_LICENSE.txt
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-digester-1.8.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/log4j-1.2.8.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/velocity-1.4.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/wsdl4j.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/.project
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/.classpath
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jettison-1.0.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xercesImpl.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jmxtools.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/struts.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/eclipselink.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/ehcache-core-2.6.0.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/ojdbc6.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xmlplsql.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/snmp4j-1.10.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons_LICENSE.txt
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/axis-ant_1.4.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-validator.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-dbcp.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/axis2-kernel-1.4.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-discovery.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jgroups.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-services.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jaas.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jboss-common.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xerces_LICENSE.txt
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jboss-minimal.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/concurrent.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/resolver.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/saaj.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-logging.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/runtime12.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jboss-system.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-codec-1.4.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jndi.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/translator.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jboss-jmx.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jms.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jakarta-oro.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jboss-serialization.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jsch-0.1.25.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/quartz-1.5.1_LICENSE.txt
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/castor-1.0.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/quartz-1.5.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/gnu-regexp-1.0.8.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/axis2-json-1.4.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jmxri.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jglue_8_1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/aqapi.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/log4j-1.2.8_LICENSE.txt
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/quartz-oracle-1.5.1.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-pool.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-digester-1.8_LICENSE.txt
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jta.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/oro-2.0.8.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jaxrpc.jar
    15:46:46.395 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-lang.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-dbutils-1.1.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/xalan.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/ejb.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/commons-resources.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jboss-cache.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/nls_charset12.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - /export/home/jenkins/jenkins-ci/jobs/**********/workspace/server/third-party-jars/jmxremote_optional.jar
    15:46:46.396 DEBUG b.ClassLoaderBuilder - -----
    15:46:46.405 DEBUG b.b.JdbcDriverHolder - To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] has been forcibly deregistered
    15:46:46.424 DEBUG .b.b.TempDirectories - Delete temporary directory: /tmp/sonar-batch782561628528002755212032328414312003
    Total time: 1:15.256s
    Final Memory: 14M/207M
    Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not create ClassLoader
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:189)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:78)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not create ClassLoader
        at org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder.create(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:62)
        at org.sonar.java.bytecode.BytecodeScanner.scan(BytecodeScanner.java:49)
        at org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidExecutor.scanBytecode(SquidExecutor.java:183)
        at org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidExecutor.scan(SquidExecutor.java:87)
        at org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidSensor.analyzeMainSources(SquidSensor.java:82)
        at org.sonar.plugins.squid.SquidSensor.analyse(SquidSensor.java:65)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:93)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ProjectModule.doStart(ProjectModule.java:139)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.analyze(BatchModule.java:131)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchModule.doStart(BatchModule.java:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.doStart(BootstrapModule.java:121)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.start(Module.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.Batch.execute(Batch.java:104)
        at org.sonar.runner.Launcher.executeBatch(Launcher.java:65)
        at org.sonar.runner.Launcher.execute(Launcher.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:186)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:99)
        at org.sonar.java.bytecode.loader.JarLoader.<init>(JarLoader.java:46)
        at org.sonar.java.bytecode.loader.SquidClassLoader.<init>(SquidClassLoader.java:48)
        at org.sonar.java.bytecode.ClassLoaderBuilder.create(ClassLoaderBuilder.java:60)
        ... 24 more
    Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure
    Finished: FAILURE
```

This does not give me too much information about the problem, but it seems that it is related to the third party jars that I pass to Sonar with the `libraries` property.

Any idea ?

Comment: In case you are wondering how to run Sonar from Jenkins in debug mode (took me some time to figure out), you have to add the property `sonar.verbose=true` to the job's build step properties. More info here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters

Answer (score 1):

The build log is incomplete, so I can't see which versions of the Sonar server and Sonar running you are using....

When analysing a Java stacktrace is always best place to start. The follow message states that Sonar is attempting to read an invalid zip file (BTW Jars are zip archives)

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

The message further up sheds some light on what Sonar was doing when it encountered this problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not create ClassLoader
```

Finally the start of the exeception message indicates which line of code threw the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.BootstrapException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not create ClassLoader
    at org.sonar.runner.Runner.delegateExecution(Runner.java:189)
```

This allows us to dig into the code:

- [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins/sonar-runner/1.3/org/sonar/runner/Runner.java#189)
- [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar.plugins/sonar-squid-java-plugin/3.1/org/sonar/java/bytecode/ClassLoaderBuilder.java#60)
- [and here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar.plugins/sonar-squid-java-plugin/3.1/org/sonar/java/bytecode/loader/SquidClassLoader.java#SquidClassLoader)

It appears to me that one of the files being loaded by Sonar is invalid, perhaps only partially downloaded from the Sonar server (Sonar manages it's own dependencies).

This diagnosis is consistent with the following debug message:

```
15:46:46.405 DEBUG b.b.JdbcDriverHolder - To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] has been forcibly deregistered
15:46:46.424 DEBUG .b.b.TempDirectories - Delete temporary directory: /tmp/sonar-batch782561628528002755212032328414312003
```

I would suggest following the advice and delete this temporary directory. 
I would go further and download the hidden ".sonar" directory that Sonar normally creates in the local workspace, forcing Sonar to download a fresh copy of all it's files.

Then try a fresh analysis and hope the problem does not occur again.